# Merging MORE THAN two dataframes with pd.merge()

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, merge, jupyter-notebook

Im trying to merge 4 csv files using pd.merge() based on a specific column ('filename'). I read that merge only works for two dataframes, and to instead try and merge the first two, then the 3rd, and then the 4th, in successive steps. This has ultimately worked, with the following code:

```
combine = pd.merge(file1, file2, on='filename', how='inner')
combine1 = pd.merge(combine, file3, on='filename', how='inner')
combine2 = pd.merge(combine1, file4, on='filename', how='inner')
```

producing the following result:

```
filename,  count_x,  count_y,  count_x,  count_y
M116_13331848_13109013422677.jpg,  21,  11,  18,  16
M116_13331848_13109013387678.jpg,  21,  13,  13,  18
M116_13331848_13109013329679.jpg,  19,  15,  16,  15
M116_13331848_13109013424677.jpg,  18,  13,  16,  15
M116_13331848_13109013385678.jpg,  17,  12,  15,  13
```

As you can see, the process has generated confusing headers on the columns. So, I tried using the suffixes parameter to control these headers. However, this only works for the first pd.merge() command, and not the second/third. Heres my script in its entirety:

[image: SCRIPT]

How can I attribute my own headers to each of the columns in the combined df?

Thank you,
R

Comment: Could you include an example of the headers before the process?

Comment: If you have the same columns in the 2 DFs you are trying to merge, to avoid duplicates the function create the _x and _y

Comment: @RoccoFortuna I have added an image of my entire script. But the four original dataframes (antns, df1, df2, df3) all just had two columns. one with the header 'filename', and the other with the header 'count'. I am trying to merge the four dfs on the 'filename' column, to compare the 'count' column across the them. Thank you! R

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be you can use parameter `suffixes` in merge to control column names. From the [pandas merge documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.25.2/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html):

> Merge DataFrames df1 and df2 with specified left and right suffixes
> appended to any overlapping columns.

In above, something like:

```
combine = pd.merge(file1, file2, on='filename', how='inner', suffixes=('_file1', '_file2'))
```

and similar on other `merge` too. That way you can know where the count came from while merging.

Example:

```
# Creating Dataframes
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'col1': ['foo', 'bar', 'baz'], 'count': [1, 2, 3]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'col1': ['foo', 'bar', 'baz'], 'count': [5, 6, 7]})
```

df1:

```
    col1    count
0   foo      1
1   bar      2
2   baz      3
```

df2:

```
    col1    count
0   foo      5
1   bar      6
2   baz      7
```

Merging

```
pd.merge(df1, df2, on='col1', suffixes=('_df1', '_df2'))
```

Result:

```
    col1    count_df1   count_df2
0   foo        1         5
1   bar        2         6
2   baz        3         7
```

## Update

Given you have four dataframes, may be you can try:

```
# Combine two of them
combine1 = pd.merge(file1, file2, on='filename', how='inner', suffixes=('_file1', '_file2'))

# Combine other two
combine2 = pd.merge(file3, file4, on='filename', how='inner', suffixes=('_file3', '_file4'))

# Now combine the combined dataframes
combine = pd.merge(combine1, combine2, on='filename', how='inner')
```

Comment: Thank you. However, this suffix method works for two dataframes, whereas I have four. As I said in the initial question, pd.merge() only works for two dataframes at a time, so I have had tomerge them in stages. I have implemented the suffix perameter for the first 2 dataframes, and this has worked. But, when I try to implement it on the other two merge commands I get various error messages depending on how I implement the parameters. I have added an image to the question above so you can see the (short) script in its entirety. @student

Comment: May be you can try the update I added to see if it works?

Comment: Fantastic this has worked perfectly. Thank you for all your help mate! @student